# Curvature with connection $\left(\frac{D^{\delta x}}{D^x_t} - r^x_t \delta t\right)$

Tags: differential-geometry

**Problem:**
I am reading the following paper, where the definition of D and P can be found on page 11: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.1671.pdf
Consider the following fibre bundle:

$$
\mathscr{B} = \{ D_t^{\pi, x}, P_t^{\pi, x} \mid (x, t \in M, \pi \in G^*) \}
$$

where M is the underlying manifold $M=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1},t\in T\}$, where $T$ is a closed $\mathbb{R}$ interval.
The $\pi$ determines gauge transformation where $G^*$ is the gauge abelian group.
I am reading a paper where a connection is defined in the following way:

$$
\chi(x, t, g)(\delta x, \delta t) =  \left(\frac{D^{\delta x}}{D^x_t} - r^x_t \delta t\right)g
$$

or as a linear combination of basis differential forms as
$$
\chi(x, t, g) = \left(\frac{1}{D_t^x} \sum_{j=1}^{N} D_j^t dx_j - r_x^t dt   \right)g
$$
$g$ is an element of $G^*$
The author then proceeds to compute the curvature using the following formula from which I know the derivation, from standard differential geometric texts:
$$
R := d\chi + [\chi, \chi] 
$$
meaning by this, that for all $(x, t, g) \in B$ and for all $\xi, \eta \in T(x,t)M$
$$
R(x, t, g)(\xi, \eta) := d\chi(x, t, g)(\xi, \eta) + [\chi(x, t, g)(\xi), \chi(x, t, g)(\eta)] 
$$

Then the author obtains, after using the commutativity of the Lie Algebra as in the following remark:

> Remark that being the Lie algebra commutative, the Lie bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]$ vanishes. After some calculations we obtain
> $$
> R(x, t, g) = \frac{g}{D_t^x} \sum_{j=1}^{N} D_j^t \left(r_x^t + \mathscr{D} \log(D_x^t) - r_j^t - \mathscr{D} \log(D_j^t)\right)  dx_j \wedge dt
> $$

where $\mathscr{D}$ is the generalized derivative.

**Question:**

How is the computation of curvature being done with this connection? I am familiar with covariant derivatives and also with exterior definition but I am not seeing how the latter is being applied. Could you provide me with a solution or at least some hints?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Definitions:

$\bullet$ $D^x_t := \sum_{j=1}^{N} x_j D^j_t$ is the weights of differnt assets multiplied by each price $D^j$ at time point $t$.$D_t^{\delta x}$ would be the value of the portfolio after chaning $x$, it could be denominated as our stardard differential $dx$.

$\bullet$ $P_{it,s} = \exp\left(-\int_s^t f_{it,\tau} \, d\tau\right) $
where
$r_{it} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} f_{it,t+\Delta t}$

$\bullet$The group action is defined as:
$(D, P) \mapsto g((D, P)) = ((D_g, P_g)$, where in the case of the terminology above it is $\pi$

so that:

$D_{i,g,t} = D_{i,t} \int_{0}^{\infty} g_{i,\tau} P_{i,t,t+\tau} \, d\tau$

and

$P^{i,g}_{t,s} = \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} g_{i,\tau} P^i_{t,s+\tau} \, d\tau }{ \int_{0}^{\infty} g_{i,\tau} P^i_{t,t+\tau} \, d\tau}$

$\bullet $ So the fibre bundle is defined as

$$
\mathscr{B} = \{ D_t^{g, x}, P_t^{g, x} \mid (x, t \in M, g \in G^*) \}=\{ D_t^{ x}, P_t^{ x},g \mid (x, t \in M, g \in G^*) \}
$$

this is defined over $M=\{x,t|x\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1},t\in T\}$ where $T$ is a closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

The projection is:

$$
\pi : \mathscr{B} \rightarrow M \\
D^{x,g}_t, P_{ts}^{x,g} \rightarrow (x, t)
$$

Comment: To increase the chances that someone will answer your question, you should define all of the objects you're working with. As is, a reader has no way of knowing precisely what $M, G^*, D_t^{\pi, x} $ or $P_t^{\pi, x}$ are.

Comment: @J.V.Gaiter Thanks for your input. I will try it and link the paper with the relevant pages.

Comment: I see it's no longer just the physicists who make notation as inaccessible as possible to mathematicians working with well-established conventions. You're going to have to make this more understandable if you expect help. I don't understand how one is dividing elements of a bundle, nor even what $\mathscr B$ remotely is.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question and added some additional information, in the hope that now it can fully be addressed from a purely mathematical perspective. Please let me know if it is not clear or is there any pertinent information missing.

Comment: I think you'll need to rewrite everything using standard notation and definitions. And why are you reading this?

Comment: @TedShifrin Although the article's author owns a PhD in hyperbolic geometry of $3$-manifolds, a quick glance at his publications reveals that the journals he publishes in are *Journal of Banking & Finance*, *Journal of Derivatives & Hedge Funds*, or *International Journal of Managerial Finance*. I guess (hope?) that the inaccessible notations do not come from the mathematical history of the author

Comment: @TedShifrin Please see my edit.

Comment: @Deane Please see my edit. I am conduction independent research, I mean it on my own.

Comment: @TedShifrin Please see my answer. Can you help me with the last step?

Answer (score 1):

LONG COMMENT:

I think to answer your question it is actually better to clarify the financial meaning of every variable and equation. Here's my speculation about this:

For the moment, hold $t$ fixed. You have a portfolio with, say, $n$ assets. $x$ represents the amount of each asset held. $D_j$ is the value of the $j$-the asset. $D^x$ is the value of the portfolio.

Your notation for $P^{?}_{??}$ is inconsistent and not fully defined. In any case, it appears to represent the return of each asset, as well as the full portfolio over time.

You never specify what $G^*$ is. It appears to be $$\require{enclose}\enclose{horizontalstrike}{(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\})^n}(\mathbb{R}_+)^n,$$ where $n$ is the number of assets.I'm not sure what the financial meaning of the action of $G^*$ is. It appears to be either percentage change in the portfolio composition or change in the rate of return.

I don't know what the financial significance of $\chi$. Nor do I recognize from its formula why it is a connection.

So you need to provide more details on both the mathematical and the financial definitions of each symbol and correct my speculations above. You'll also have to explain why $\chi$ fits the definition of a connection. None of us are going to read the paper and figure out the meaning of this notation. If you know the precise definition of a principal bundle and a connection on it, you should be able to translate everything into standard mathematical notation. The financial interpretation also helps us understand the role of the connection and curvature in that context.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have posted an answer but I am not sure about the last step. I do not know how I would compute the partial derivative so that the result would be the one desired.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing some other proofs of results that use this connection, I was able to write this down, but the last step is still missing. I do not know how the author deals with partial derivative.

$d \mathscr{X}(x,t,g)=d \left( \left(\frac{1}{D_t^x} \sum_{j=1}^{N} D_j^t dx_j - r_x^t dt   \right)g \right)$

where it was used $d=d_x+d_t=d_x+\mathscr{D}$

$d(-r^*_t dt)=dx(-r^x_t dt)=-\sum \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}r^x_t dx_j\wedge dt=\sum \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}r^x_t dx_j\wedge dt$

So $\mathscr{R}(x,t,g)=g\left( \sum \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}(\log(D^x_t))   \right)dx_i\wedge dx_j +g(\sum_{i<j}\mathscr{D}\frac{\partial \log(D^x_t)}{dx_i}+\sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}r_t^x)dt\wedge dx_j$

Since $dx_i\wedge dx_j=-dx_j\wedge dx_i$, the first part is zero:

So $\mathscr{R}(x,t,g)=g\sum_{i<j} 
   \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\mathscr{D} \log(D^x_t){dx_i}+\sum_{j}r_t^x)dt\wedge dx_j=\\ \frac{g}{D_t^x} \sum_{j=1}^{N} D_j^t \left(r_x^t + \mathscr{D} \log(D_x^t) - r_j^t - \mathscr{D} \log(D_j^t)\right)  dx_j \wedge dt$

I am not sure how to compute this last step. I know it has to be equal, but how?